# Workflow for compiling and installing a single existing kernel module?

Tags: networking, kernel, icmp

I am working on creating a patch in the Linux kernel. All of my work occurs in the file `net/ipv4/icmp.c` (and associated header.)

So far, every time I want to test my code, I run `make -j $(getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN) deb-pkg LOCALVERSION=-custom-version-XYZ` , then reboot my machine and choose `custom-verson-XYZ` from the boot menu.

I learned this from https://wiki.ubuntu.com/KernelTeam/GitKernelBuild

I believe there is a kernel module for ICMP, and it might be possible to just compile and install that module without rebooting. I don't see any ICMP kernel module when I run `find /lib/modules/$(uname -r) -type f -name '*.ko*'`, so I'm not sure if this is true.

If there, is, what would the workflow for compiling and installing just ICMP look like?

Comment: There is no module for ICMP nor IPv4. so whatever answer about compiling a single module, it won't help for your case. As a side note, even if IPv6 can have such module (the whole IPv6, not just ICMPv6), it's special enough that once loaded it can't be unloaded (thus still requiring a reboot).

Comment: Thank you. I find running make deb-pkg takes ~an hour or two. Is there any faster way to be able to test smaller changes, even if it involves a reboot? The reason I’ve been using make deb-pkg is because I like that you can name the kernel something specific (otherwise, all compilations have the same generic name, eg linux-5.11)

Comment: @A.B Do you know if I have any other options to speed up test times?

Comment: Maybe only using make bzImage rather than deb-pkg. If I knew for sure I would be making an answer, not a comment.